how do i find the topological relationship between 2 areas (DE-9IM matrix and its interpretation in topological terms are required)
I am trying to write the SQL query to find the topological relationship between 2 areas (DE-9IM matrix and its interpretation in topological terms are required), but my query has been returning 0 rows
SELECT 
    n.asset_cd, 
    c.name AS community_name, 
    ST_Relate(n.geom3776, c.geom3776, '*********') AS relationship
FROM 
    "Lab2"."calgis_paris_natural_area_c_v" AS n
INNER JOIN 
    "Lab2"."calgis_adm_community_district" AS c
ON 
    c.geom3776 && n.geom3776
WHERE 
    n.asset_cd = 'SIL245'
AND 
    c.name = 'Silver Springs';

